# Problems with yfinance package in Python

Tags: python, yfinance

I am currently trying to use the yfinance package in Python, but am running into problems. When I run

```
import yfinance as yf
msft = yf.Ticker('MSFT')
msft.info
```

However, When I run this code I get the error message of :Exception: yfinance failed to decrypt Yahoo data response. WARNING: No decryption keys could be extracted from JS file. Falling back to backup decrypt methods.

I am unsure what to do, for a month ago, this same code worked for me. I am running jupyter notebooks on mac. I redownloaded python, but am to no avail. I followed the advice from >https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance>.

Comment: Can you share which version of `yfinance` are you using? as of now `yfinance==0.2.24` seems to be executing the same code block without any issues.

Comment: yfinance                      0.2.36
Problem exists

Answer (score 2):

Read through the discussion [here](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/1329).
As to " for a month ago, this same code worked for me", [here](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/1246) definitely gives a sense that Yahoo has been actively adjusting things on their end **very recently** and changes need to be made to accomodate that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use yahooquery, another package just like yfinance using the Yahoo API and is a bit faster than yfinance
You can find documentation here https://pypi.org/project/yahooquery/1.1.0/